# How to update submodule url with git mirror

Tags: git, git-submodules

I migrated my repo via use command `git clone --mirror myrepo.git`

My repo have a git submodule, the submodule url has changed.

How do I update submodule url in mirror folder?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible<sup>1</sup> to do any work in a mirror clone.

Instead of a mirror clone, make a regular (non-mirror) clone.  Work in that.  The URL is in the `.gitmodules` file, which you can open, edit, `git add`, and `git commit` as usual.

Use a non-recursive clone so that `git clone` does not try to create the submodule using the old URL.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it is *possible*, but it's not a good idea.